# Form data display on terminal & doesn't save in postgres database django

Tags: python-3.x, django

In my cause of learning django, I decided to start with small projects, I'm working on a simple registration page. I have my form on the home page (index.html). And I have a view.py page I pass all the data from the form to my postgres db. I realise data does not save in db, instead all the registration data display in terminal and the url bar. Here's my code;

Form (index.html)

```
<form action="/index/" method="POST">

              {% csrf_token %}

              <div><p><label for="fName">First Name</label></div>
                  <div><input type="text" name="fName"></input></div>
              </p>
              
              <p>
                  <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="lName"></input>
              </p>
              
              <p>
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input type="text" name="email"></input>
              </p>

              
                <div><p><label for="uName">Username</label></div>
                <div><input type="text" name="uName"></input></div>
              </p>
          
              <p>
                <label for="password1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="Password1"></input>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="Password2"></input>
              </p>

              <div> <p><input type="submit"></input></p> </div>
            
            </form>
```

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth

def index(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    first_name = request.POST['fName']
    last_name = request.POST['lName']
    username = request.POST['uName']
    password1 = request.POST['password1']
    password2 = request.POST['password2']
    email = request.POST['email']
    
    
    
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password1, email=email, 
    first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
    user.save()
    print('user created')
    return redirect('/')
else:

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Database setting on settings.py

DATABASES = {
'default': {

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'bookconf',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'olumide',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
}
```

}

I suspect the data is collected and them skip to executed this `return render(request, 'index.html')` because after I enter submit, the home page(index.html) gets reloaded.

In addition, I'm certain psycopg2 is installed. No data gets saved in the db and no error messages except the message below.

Message on terminal

[03/Sep/2020 04:22:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25753
[03/Sep/2020 04:22:37] "GET /?csrfmiddlewaretoken=LtMIZL5z9yGYElCkunBrkMt2mS7rMr90cyxlHPVUfiA6hpaF80Phfpjbrp6RUVpj&fName=Ken&lName=Cole&email=kcole%40mail.com&uName=k.cole&Password1=1122&Password2=1122 HTTP/1.1" 200 25753

Ideas on how to fix this will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please also show your settings for your database from `settings.py` file and also the console output you are getting. Also, one thing, you don't have to do `user.save()` after calling `User.objects.create_user` as it automatically saves the data for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Noopur Phalak, I just updated the post with my db settings from settings.py. Also the console output doesnt show any error.

Comment: The message you have on your terminal says that you have triggered a GET request, but the form in the html file has POST method...Check if you are actually making a GET request or a POST request to the server...